# How to avoid duplicate values in a sorted string array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, duplicates, hashset

I found this code which was meant to avoid duplicate values for numbers so I changed it to consider String elements.It successfully avoids duplicate names when printing, but it does not sort the names in alphabetic order.

I also hope that it does not print a specific element "vacant", because it will be later updated with a name through an input.

**This is based on a booking system to sort names in ascending order,so empty elements are called "vacant".**
Please can someone help me.

```
String[] a ={"Anne","Anne","Afrid","vacant","vacant","Sammy","Dora","vacant"};
HashSet<String> nameSet = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < a.length;i++){
    nameSet.add(a[i]);
}
for (String name: nameSet) {
    System.out.println(name+" ");
}
```

Comment: My first thought is to store the names in an `ArrayList` instead and let it take care of the vacant elements. In any case, if you use `TreeSet` instead of `HashSet`, the elements will be sorted. Then you just need to check `! name.equals("vacant")` in the loop where you print the names.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code to do the following,

1. Removed duplicates
2. Removed Vacant
3. Removes anything that has null
4. Sorts the list ignore case
5. Prints them

```java
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        //Input
        String[] a = { "Anne", "Anne", "Afrid", "vacant", "vacant", "Sammy", "Dora", "vacant" };
        List<String> list = Stream.of(a) //Convert to Stream
                .filter(Objects::nonNull) //Remove Null values
                .sorted(new IgnoreCaseStringSorter()) //Sort ignore case
                .distinct() //Remove duplicates
                .filter(name -> !name.equalsIgnoreCase("vacant")) //Remove "vacant"
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); //Convert to list
        System.out.println("Names: ");
        list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);//Print the list

    }
    static class IgnoreCaseStringSorter implements Comparator<String> {
        // Used for sorting in ascending order
        public int compare(String a, String b) {
            return a.compareToIgnoreCase(b);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Names: 
Afrid
Anne
Dora
Sammy
```